# create 2 div display is inline-block bcoz i want both div side by side but here another div is moving upward

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn html and css and here i have created 2 div display is inline-block bcoz i want both div side by side but here another div is moving upward please help

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto display:block;
}

.nameh {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  color: #ff1515;
}

.photo {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
}

.about {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.maind {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2> Hi! I Am Shaikh Altamash FrontEnd Developer Based On Mumbai India </h2>
<div class="photo"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800.jpg" alt=""></img>
</div>

<div class="about">
  <h3>As You Know i am <span> Shaikh Altamash </span> Based Mumbai I am looking for an opportunity to prove myself. i want to master some skills and do something extraordinary . i want financial Freedome in my life</h3>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzU9B.jpg)

Comment: if you want to align block-level element next toe ach other such as `div`s then you should use `Flexbox`. Also note, that `<img>` is an empty tag and as such it has no closing tag. `</img>` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap both `div`s inside a container and apply `display: flex` to it. To center both `div`s you can use: `justify-content: center`.

remove the `display: inline-block`-properties and the invalid `</img>` tag which does not exsist.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  color: #ff1515;
}

.photo,
.about {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2> Hi! I Am Shaikh Altamash FrontEnd Developer Based On Mumbai India </h2>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="photo"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="about">
    <h3>As You Know i am <span> Shaikh Altamash </span> Based Mumbai I am looking for an opportunity to prove myself. i want to master some skills and do something extraordinary . i want financial Freedome in my life</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can give them all the CSS style`display: inline;` by giving them all a class called "inline" by using `<div class="inline">` and in your style tag or stylesheet put `.inline { display: inline; }` or by giving the divs a style attribute by replacing '' with `<div style="display: inline;">`

Answer (score -2):

You can work with spans or give them a mutual class and give it a style

```
    display:inline;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Like This !!!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    span.a {
      display: inline; /* the default for span */
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid blue;  
      background-color: yellow; 
    }
    
    span.b {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid blue;    
      background-color: yellow; 
    }
    
    span.c {
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid blue;    
      background-color: yellow; 
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1>The display Property</h1>
    
    <h2>display: inline</h2>
    <div> <span class="a">1</span> <span class="a">2</span>  </div>
    
    <h2>display: inline-block</h2>
    <div> <span class="b">1</span> <span class="b">2</span> </div>
    
    <h2>display: block</h2>
    <div> <span class="c">1</span> <span class="c">2</span>  </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```